# Missing property after copy (iOS)

Tags: ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

My project is ARC-enabled, I have two models something like:

`Category`:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (assign, nonatomic) Category *parent;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *children;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *subCategories;
@end
```

`Product`:

```
@interface Child : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) Category *category;
@end
```

To avoid reference loop, and to deploy on iOS 4.x, I set the parent property of Child as `assign` but not `weak`.

From JSON data, I can get a tree containing my categories and products. When I use the tree to enumerate, all the things went perfect. And I have a recursion method to search products with name matching a keyword. The method is something as followed:

```
- (NSArray *)productsWithKeyword:(NSString *)keyword
{
    NSMutableArray *filteredProducts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (Category *cat in self.children) {
        NSArray *subResult = [cat productsWithKeyword:keyword];
        [filteredProducts addObjectsFromArray:subResult];
    }

    return [filteredProducts copy];
}
```

The problem is when I'm using the returned array, I can get the right `category` property. But from the second time and on, the `category` property becomes 0 (caught from debugger).

So, what's the problem? And what's the fix to the problem?

Comment: I've also tried to set the parent and category properties to be strong. But the problem still exists.

Comment: OMG, it's my own stupid problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a reference loop you want to make one object have a weak reference to the other not have both with weak references to each other. I think what's happening in this case is that the product doesn't own the category and the category doesn't own the product, so ARC releases both of the objects assuming no one claims them.

FIX: make one of these objects the "parent" of the other.

Comment: The root tree array retains them all.